# how to represent mathematically a matrix with distinct values

Tags: matrices

I would like to write a mathematical expression for the following matrix

```
A = (5 7 3
     9 1 8
     2 6 4)
```

in words, the matrix "A" contains the values from 1 to N and each aij is a distinct value

ex:
A = { aij; aij are distinct; i = {1,2,3}, j = {1,2,3} }

how to write it?

Comment: Maybe you mean a [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)?

Comment: no, it is a 3x3 matrix but the text is not formated

Comment: Then maybe you mean a [Latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)?

Comment: A $n \times n$ latin square has the numbers $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ on every row and column such that no number occurs twice in any row or column. The $n \times n$ matrix in this problem is a permutation of $[n^2]$ reshaped to be a $n \times n$ matrix. I'd probably write out what $A$ is in words in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$\mathcal{A} =\{ A \in M_{n \times n} : a_{ij} \in [n^2], (i,j) \neq (k,l) \implies a_{ij} \neq a_{kl}  \}$$ where $[n] \triangleq \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Then, you can say $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

Though saying what $A$ is in words is probably a better option, e.g. $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are in $[n^2]$ such that no two entries are the same.